# AWS SDK 1.11.844 is throwing Continuously ERROR while connecting to Kinesis Stream

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, spring-cloud-stream, aws-java-sdk

**I am Using Spring Cloud Data Stream and Kinesis Spring Binder to connect to Kinesis:** https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis-docs/src/main/asciidoc/overview.adoc
By default, it uses aws-sdk 1.11.415 and which can't be used for Assumed Role while deploying in Kubernetes environment (AWS EKS). I have figured out that I need to upgrade the library to aws-sdk 1.11.844 to support the WebIdentityToken based credential provider. This is working in Kubernetes. Now from my local machine, I am trying to connect to Kinesis by enabling instance profile (disabling the WebIdentityToken based flow), it keeps on throwing below error and not connecting. when I comment this upgraded library it goes back to aws-sdk 1.11.415 which is working as expected. But I need to upgrade this for WebIdentityToken based credential provider.

Please help me if anybody having any solution for this. I can't change to AWS SDKV2 as Spring Binder will not support that. Any other solution will be helpful.

```
    com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to connect to service endpoint: 
    at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.doReadResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:100) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.844.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.doReadResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:70) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.844.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.internal.InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.readResource(InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.java:75) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.844.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.readResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:66) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.844.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils.getItems(EC2MetadataUtils.java:402) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.844.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils.getData(EC2MetadataUtils.java:371) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.844.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.context.support.env.AwsCloudEnvironmentCheckUtils.isRunningOnCloudEnvironment(AwsCloudEnvironmentCheckUtils.java:38) ~[spring-cloud-aws-context-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
......
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at com.baxter.renal.app.s3.poc.CAPDTreatmentUploadApplication.main(CAPDTreatmentUploadApplication.java:22) [classes/:?]
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:107) ~[?:?]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your local machine doesn't have an instance profile.

If you look at the stack trace, you'll see `EC2MetadataUtils.getItems()`. This is trying to read from the [instance metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html) endpoint, `http://169.254.169.254`. On an EC2 instance that returns quickly; on your local machine it will time-out because that IP address doesn't exist.

If you're looking to consume AWS services from your local machine, you will have to use a credentials provider that retrieves the information locally. I recommend using [DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.html), which looks for local configuration (either in `$HOME/.aws` or via environment variables or system properties), and also supports instance profiles (in case you're running on an EC2 instance).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will check. However, I am wondering how the 1.11.415 version is working in my machine without any error.  I have turned on the Spring instance-profile configuration (cloud.aws.credentials.instance-profile=true) in the application and connecting AWS through ADFS and configured profile. All issues starts only when upgrading to the library version which is necessary for K8 env.

Comment: @user3792889 - All I can tell you is what I see in the stack trace. Anything else you'll have to do yourself.

Comment: This was very helpful in solving the continuous error. It stopped.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem locally. Turning off `ContextInstanceDataAutoConfiguration` is the best solution. Just add

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude: org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextInstanceDataAutoConfiguration
```

to your application.yml file.

Comment: This was very helpful in solving the  display of error in the console. I have used above + this solution. Thank you!